# Button Menu Android

Tags: android, button

I am trying to make a donation menu for my app. I have figured out the part that when a user clicks donate, more buttons come up saying how much. Now, I want to be able to have the amount buttons go away if they click the same button again. I want the regular DonateButton to remain. How would I come about doing that?

I have already set it as invisible using `purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Here is the code for clicking the button and the other buttons appearing:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.DonateButton:

              purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              purchaseButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              purchaseButton3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        case R.id.Donate:
                if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
                        BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "donate");
                        // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded
        } else {
                Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
        }

                break;
        default:
                // nada
                Log.i(TAG,"default. ID: "+v.getId());
                break;

case R.id.Donatetwo:
    if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "donate2");
            // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded
} else {
    Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
}

    break;

case R.id.Donatethree:
    if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "donate3");
            // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded
} else {
    Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
}

    break;
        }
}
```

Screenshot of what I mean:

IMAGE URL (DON'T HAVE 10 REPUTATION YET):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMdhS.png

What I am trying to say is.

- The app comes up just showing the "Donate!" Button. =>
- The user clicks the "Donate!" Button. =>
- The buttons "Donate $1", "Donate $3", and "Donate $5" appear. =>
  I NEED HELP FROM HERE
- A user wants to close the "Donate $1", "Donate $3", and "Donate $5" Buttons. =>
- To close them, they click the "Donate!" which was the button they used to open it all. =>
- The "Donate $1", "Donate $3", and "Donate $5" go away.

I want it to still allow them to open and close those buttons more than once though.

Comment: question is not clear **amount buttons go away if they click the same button again** means what? Please post screenshots then it makes clear.

Comment: I have added the picture and tried to make it clearer. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple state variable should do.

put this in your field definition area:

```
boolean areButtonAmountVisible = false;
```

and this code as your `onClick()`:

```
case R.id.DonateButton:

   if( areButtonAmountVisible )
   {
       areButtonAmountVisible = false;
       purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       purchaseButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       purchaseButton3.setVisibility(View.FONE);
   }
   else
   {
       areButtonAmountVisible = true;
       purchaseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       purchaseButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       purchaseButton3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was simple, I just couldn't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Use `getVisibility()` method to know the visible state of button.

```
int visibility;


visibility = button.getVisibility();
if(visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

You have to check like this for every button.

---

I will suggest one more thing.

Take a global variable and use it as notifier, use below code in all button click functions.

```
boolean again = false;

if (again) {
    // make all invisible
    again = false;
} else {
    // make all visible
    again = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I already got it to work from the above post. I appreciate your help though! :)

Comment: see, after i asked for screenshot and clarity in question, you got answer. ok. so don't forget to post question clearly.